# how to hide one div and hide another on hovering image or text?

Tags: javascript, css

Hi suppose below is the code

```
<h1>Hover Me</h1>
<div id="showme">Show</div>
<div id="hideme"><Hide</div>
```

If i hover on  text the div with id showme should be shown and hide me should be hidden.Please provide me solution either in jscript or css.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on `:hover` of `h1` the div will be `visible` and other div vill be `hidden`

```css
h1:hover ~ #showme,
#hideme {
  display: block
}
h1:hover ~ #hideme,
#showme {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<h1>Hover Me</h1>
<div id="showme">Show</div>
<div id="hideme">Hide</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible jquery solution:

```
<h1 class='hover'>Hover Me</h1>
<div id="showme">Show</div>
<div id="hideme">Hide</div>

$('#hideme').show();
$('.hover').hover(function () {
    $('#hideme').hide();
}, function(){
    $('#hideme').show();
});
```

[**FIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/h895ovyo/)